# Removing HTML elements with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove HTML DOM object by its ID, that contains special characters(dots, commas etc). I tried to use this code that escapes those characters but it's not working (element its not being removed):

```js
var file_html_id ="#"+ filename.replace(/[!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@\[\\\]^`{|}~]/g, "\\\\$&");
console.log(file_html_id);
$(file_html_id).remove();
```

where filename its the ID. It's worth to mention that string with escaped characters is displayed as expected. And if I "hardcode" that string it works fine... So where the problem might be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to escape the characters yourself you could try a couple of other ways:

1. Use [jQuery's escapeSelector()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/) on the id string. This will escape any special characters in the string. Note `escapeSelector` was added in v3.0 of jQuery. View how they are doing the escaping [here](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/eabce51ea7360c4507da2eeaec2633378de4ec8d/src/sizzle.js#L154)
   if interested.

   ```
   $( '#'+ $.escapeSelector('theText') )
   ```
2. Use an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) instead of trying to escape all the possible characters for an id selector

   ```
   $('[id="idHere"]')
   ```

   This however will select multiple elements if for some bizarre reason you have multiple elements with the same id.

Demo

```js
var id = "some,weird®,id";
var id2 = "some,other®,id";

$('#'+ $.escapeSelector(id2)  ).css({border:'1px solid green'});

$('[id="'+id+'"]').css({border:'1px solid red'});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="some,weird®,id"></div>
<br/>
<div id="some,other®,id"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Both your methods work. Do you maybe know why the code i have posted isn't working ?

Comment: You were adding too many escape slashes, `"\\$&"` instead of `"\\\\$&"` would have worked.